# VLOOKUP function in Tableau

Tags: vlookup, tableau-api

I am newbie in tableau. I have two data sources, an excel file and a connection database. I need to find a description ID in the excel file (table1), and paste it into the table database (table2).

**Example:**

The Excel file (table1):

```
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|  Id   | description1  | description2   |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| 01:01 | soft          | install soft   |
| 12:04 | soft          | uninstall soft |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

The connected database (table2):

```
+-------+---------+------+
|  ID   |  group  | name |
+-------+---------+------+
| 01:01 | IT      | bob  |
| 12:04 | Finance | joni |
+-------+---------+------+
```

This is what I want as output:

```
+-------+---------+------+--------------+----------------+
|  ID   |  group  | name | description1 |  description2  |
+-------+---------+------+--------------+----------------+
| 01:01 | IT      | bob  | soft         | install soft   |
| 12:04 | Finance | joni | soft         | uninstall soft |
+-------+---------+------+--------------+----------------+
```

How can I find this information using ID?

Answer (score 3):

So to do this you should be able to connect both excel files to tableau. Therefore you will have two data sources. You then will form a relationship between the two sheets based on a common id, in this case it will be the field "ID". You can then drag in the pills you need to the shelf to form the table as above.

1. Connect both data excel data sources to workbook
2. Navigate to the sheet1 and you will see both data sources listed in the top left hand corner.
3. Select the first sheet and navigate to Data-> Edit Relationship(on the top menu bar)
4. Select the "custom" in the bullet menu
5. Select the add button, and in the pop window choose to link the data on ID to id
6. Select OK
7. Your data is now blended and you can drag in your fields from both data sources and get the results you listed.

Apologies for not sharing screen shots but I cant upload at the moment.

Here's a link on defining relationships.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#multipleconnections_relationships.html